# Git revert misunderstanding

Tags: git

Can someone explain how git-revert works.

Currently I made some mistakes in my app and I pushed the changes to master branch. Now I found working commit and I want to reset my master branch to that working commit.

So my question is, what will I do if I type `git-revert 145bb80`, will all of my files be the same as they were originally on this commit: 145bb80 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is, what will I do if I type git-revert 145bb80, will all of my files be the same as they were originally on this commit: 145bb80 ?

Good question, and the answer is no.  I imagine you came from Subversion land (as did I) and revert meant something different--it was an action on your working copy, rather then the repository.  In Git land, `git revert` is meant to reverse the changes of a single commit, not to restore the whole tree to a particular state.

The command you are looking for is `git reset`--though there are some forms that are meant for the working tree and index.  There are several different forms.  If you want to make it so that your branch points at `145bb80`, then you would run `git reset --hard 145bb80` while on that branch.  Two things will happen as a result:

1) Your branch will forcibly be made to point at `145bb80`.  Any other commits that have happened will be lost.  This is a form of history rewriting so be sure it's what you want to do.  You will also get an error if you try to push the branch.  It will tell you it's not a fast-forward commit, and that you need to `git push --force` to force it on the remote repository.  Again, be careful.  Be sure it's what your team wants.

2) `git reset --hard` will drop any local changes in your index and working tree.  So if you want to keep them, you need to stash them before using `git reset --hard`.

There is also another choice that's far less dangerous.  That would be to revert the revert.  It sounds a bit silly, but it let's your history continue in a fast-forward manner.

Also, if you'd simply like a copy of a file as it was in `145bb80`, then you can do that too using:

```
git checkout 145bb80 -- path/to/file
```

You could use the following to restore the tree to the contents it was in `145bb800`:

```
git checkout 145bb80 -- .
```

Again though, be careful with that kind of command as you can lose work.

Your best bet is to simply revert the *bad commit(s)* with `git revert` to avoid undoing work by others.

Comment: Great answer, though I would also like mention `git checkout -p`, which allows you to easily "revert" parts of a commit.

Comment: I'm the only person which use this branch. So to summarize, if I do git reset --hard 145bb80 I will have the same files as they were before?

Comment: git reset is not really appropriate here since he pushed his changes upstream and using reset will just get your tree in a state where you can no longer push. Git checkout would work indeed but would have a similar effect as simply using git revert in the sense that you are creating a new commit.

Comment: Ok now I'm confused, can someone just tell me how to revert to previous working state so I can push again if I make any changes

Comment: Thank you @RobW.  That's a good point, though it doesn't really operate at the commit level.  It's more like a range between `<commit>` and HEAD unless you know a better way to do that?

Comment: @Alen it depends on what you want to do.  Have others made commits?  Are you working with a team?  If so, reverting the *bad commits* with `git revert` is the way to go.

Comment: I don't have a team, I'm using laravel forge so I need to use git to push changes to my server, so I'm the only one who use this branch

Comment: @Alen I didn't see your previous comment.  If you're the only one using the branch, then yes `git reset --hard 145bb80` will do the trick.

Comment: but @JillesvanGurp said I won't be able to push new changes

Comment: Ok I just said my prayers and executed git reset --hard 145bb80 and it worked. Huh :) thank you a ton !!

Answer (score 1):

Git revert creates a new commit that is the reverse of the commit that you want to undo. So, that definitely is what you want since you already pushed your changes and you need to undo your change upstream as well (I assume). It will indeed get your files back in the state where you want them to be. It won't wipe out the history of your mistake of course.

You can also use revert for a range of commits:

```
git revert OLDER_COMMIT^..NEWER_COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have pushed the changes to remote repository, you'd better not use command `git reset`, especially with `--hard`, which is dangerous. Remote repository may not allow force push, since `git reset` will modify your commit history and make your push non-forward merge. And even it's allowed, it may also destroyed the history of others that have already pulled from git server (remote central repository).

Using `git revert` is preferred. It will create a new commit to reverse the effect of your earlier wrong commit.